# Adding a tab to the login page

Tags: 7

On the Login page, there are 3 tabs i.e. "Create new account", "Log in", and "Request new password". Are there modules out there that let us add more? If not, how can I achieve this manually?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) with type as 'MENU_LOCAL_TASK'. So that your menu path will be like 'user/your_path'.

Ex:

`function my_module_menu($items) {
  $items['user/my-path] = array(
    'title' => 'Some title'
    'page callback => 'your callback',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK, 
  );
  return $items;

}`

If you are using views to print this page, you can set menu as Menu tab in path options.